# Creating a stack view in Android

Tags: android, android-design-library, stackview

I am working on stack view and need something like this.

[image]

I need a vertical stackview which shows the pages name below as shown in the picture, I have no idea about how stack view works and how it functions. Is an example available?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [Swipecards](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards) or [SwipeStack](https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack) library. I'm using Swipecards with some layout behind it to create impression of view stack like below:

[image: SwipeStack]

Comment: but what if i want the previous view back?

Comment: Hmmm.. good question. You can just stack it on the back and then creating something like reverse in those libraries. I don't know how to handle it exactly but I'm pretty sure that possible.

Comment: you can save the swiped views into onSaveInstanceState() and restore them with onRestoreInstanceState()

Comment: I didnt get you?